# Postman UI number variable?

Tags: postman

Is it possible in Postman to set a variable to a number value, or must it be a string? The API I'm writing requires a user_id integer value passed through as a header, but it looks like Postman can't really mock that if I can only use strings as header values.

Am I missing something?

Comment: All HTTP request header values are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Phil, All HTTP request header values are strings. Therefore, Postman will always send strings.